# How to UPSERT with clojure.java.jdbc

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure, conflict, upsert

I use insert-multi! in clojure.java.jdbc to insert multiple rows into a Postgresql table. For some reason, I get duplicate primary keys in the rows to be inserted. These have to be ignored and the rest have to be inserted normally. So I need to "upsert" with the ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING syntax. This is how to use clojure.java.jdbc:

```
(jdbc/insert-multi! db-spec :fruit
                [:name :cost]
                [["Pomegranate" 585] 
                 ["Kiwifruit" 93]])
```

but I actually have to do the below:

```
INSERT INTO fruit (name, cost)
VALUES ("Pomegranate", 585), 
       ("Kiwifruit", 93) 
ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING;
```

Would there be any workaround for this? Should I just prepare insert queries in strings on my own?

Comment: please share your table structure as well

Answer (score 3):

You might find HoneySQL helpful since it supports more sophisticated `INSERT` statements and generates a SQL string + parameters vector that can be used with `jdbc/execute!`:

https://cljdoc.org/d/seancorfield/honeysql/2.0.0-alpha2/doc/getting-started/postgresql-support

Comment: HoneySQL, a higher-level DSL. It was introduced in the overview of clojure.java.jdbc. Thank you, Sean. Great job!

Answer (score 1):

You can use HoneySQL with [HoneySQL PostgreSQL helpers](https://github.com/nilenso/honeysql-postgres) to use [upsert](https://github.com/nilenso/honeysql-postgres#upsert) (`ON CONFLICT DO ...`):

```
(require '[honeysql-postgres.helpers :as sql.helpers])

(-> (insert-into :fruit)
    (values [{:cost 585 :name "Pomegrenade"}
             {:cost 93 :name "Kiwifruit"}])
    (sql.helpers/upsert (-> (sql.helpers/on-conflict :name)
                            (sql.helpers/do-nothing)))
    (sql.helpers/returning :*)
    sql.helpers/format)
=> ["INSERT INTO distributors (cost, name) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?) ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING RETURNING *" 
    585 "Pomegrenade" 
    93 "Kiwifruit"]
```